# Sending video frames to client

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, tkinter

I am currently using OpenCV to read video frames.

On the server side I serialize the frame using cPickle.dumps():

```
flag, frame = cap.read()
frame = cPickle.dumps(frame)
client_socket.sendall(frame)
```

On the client side I serialize the frame using cPickle.loads():

```
data = sock.recv(4000)
frame = cPickle.loads(data) # ValueError: insecure string pickle
self.ImageLabel.configure(image=frame) # Want to show the frame in Tkinter
self.ImageLabel.image = frame
self.ImageLabel.grid(row=4, columnspan=40)
```

cPickle.loads(data) causes ValueError: insecure string pickle. What am I doing wrong? I want to read the frame on the client side and show it in tkinter window. I have looked up every where for more than 9 hours but couldn't find a solution.

Edit 1:

I also tried this:

server side

```
flag, frame = cap.read()
if flag:
    size = sys.getsizeof(frame)
    client_socket.send(str(size))
    client_socket.sendall(cPickle.dumps(frame.tolist()))
```

client side

```
size = sock.recv(4000)
data = sock.recv(int(size))
frame = cPickle.loads(data) # Causes EOFError
```

Edit 2:
server side

```
flag, frame = cap.read()
if flag:
   frame = cPickle.dumps(frame)
   size = len(frame)
   p = struct.pack("I", size)
   client_socket.send(p)
   client_socket.sendall(frame)
```

client side

```
sizep = sock.recv(struct.calcsize("I"))
data_size = struct.unpack("I",sizep)
print type (data_size) # tuple - has (11026730, )
data = sock.recv(int(data_size[0]))
frame = cPickle.loads(data) # ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre cap.read() is a function of OpenCV. It's giving a <type 'numpy.ndarray'> object

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre cPickle.dumps(frame.tolist()) causes EOFError when trying to cPickle.load(data).
I am not sure if self.ImageLabel.configure(image=frame) accepts a ndarray.

Comment: Can you print `frame` before sending it? Seems that something is corrupt here...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Result of print frame: http://pasted.co/a6dce83c
where frame = cPickle.dumps(frame.tolist())

Comment: you didn't add the `  ..., ` yourself do you?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I didn't add that myself. This is the result which appears on terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You're receiving at most 4000 bytes of data with the following

```
data = sock.recv(4000)
```

But the message is bigger than that. You have to fully read the message or it is truncated, which explains the pickle error. For example do like this:

```
packets = []
while True:
    b = sock.recv(4096)
    if b:
        packets.append(b)
    else:
        break

data = "".join(packets)
```

that will read the socket until there's nothing to read anymore. I put each packet in a list, so I can use `str.join` afterwards (faster than string concatenation).

Now `data` can be loaded into pickle.

Note: it doesn't solve the `self.ImageLabel.configure(image=frame)` for sure. Make sure to pass the expected array type to this method.

Edit: now that you have edited your question, you have even more problems.

- first you're computing the size of the object *before* serialization using pickle, which is incorrect, you should use `len(picked object)`
- then you're reading the size using `recv(4000)`: you just consumed a part of your buffer by doing this, and you don't know the size of the integer as string so size problem isn't solved. If you need to send the size first, you need to encode it using `struct.pack` and decode it on the client side using `struct.unpack`.
- When you have the correct size, you can read your data.

Here's my proposal (you'll need to import `struct`):

server side:

```
flag, frame = cap.read()
if flag:
    data = cPickle.dumps(frame)  # serialize
    data_size = len(data)        # nb of bytes of serialized data
    p = struct.pack("I",data_size) # encode size
    client_socket.send(p)  # send encoded size
    client_socket.sendall(data)  # send serialized data
```

client side:

```
sizep = sock.recv(struct.calcsize("I")) # first thing: recieved encoded size
data_size = struct.unpack("I",sizep)  # decode size
data = sock.recv(data_size)          # read data size
frame = cPickle.loads(data)          # unserialize
```

Comment: Please see my edit. The server will send many frames. So I first sent the size of a frame before sending the actual frame but it still causes an error. If the size of message was a problem, wouldn't this have solved that?

Comment: I tried your solution using struct. It is still giving ValueError: insecure string pickle. Please see Edit 2.

Comment: can you print size before emission and after?